# Creating a Parquet Folder from a very large CSV with R

Tags: r, parquet, arrow-functions

I am trying to work with a 200GB csv using R. I'm exploring the arrow package and have been able to using the open_dataset() function to point to the file.

```
arrow_data <- open_dataset(
  sources = large.csv", 
  format = "csv", 
  schema = schema(
    col1 = string(),
    col2 = string(),
    col3 = string(),
    col4 = string())
```

I would like to output the data to a parquet folder for further efficent analysis on the data. The code below looks to be what I need to do this where the write_dataset would create a folder for value in the group_var column.

```
arrow_data %>% 
  group_by(group_var) %>% 
  write_dataset(path = pq_path, format = "parquet")
```

However, when I run this it produces a few folders and then fails with the error below.

```
Error: Invalid: In CSV column #3: Row #12250498: CSV conversion error to string: invalid UTF8 data
```

Online suggestions are to pre-clean the csv, however, how to do that is seemingly difficult given the size and that I can't read it efficiently.

Can anyone offer some guidance on how I might be able to proceed?

Comment: Do you know what encoding was using in the original CSV file? Are you 100% sure it was using UTF-8? Are you also sure you have the entire contents of the file correctly downloaded without any corruption? Like have you checked MD5 sums or anything (if available)? It sounds like the data is corrupted or incorrectly encoded. Without knowing exactly how that might have happened, it's hard to recommend a general fix.

Comment: Beyond the above, a 200GB CSV file is not going to live in memory of the average personal computer. Even with appropriate data structures that is going to be very difficult to negotiate. A good way might be to open a connection and read and write lines. This article suggests a viable option. And you could start with just a few lines and test for data structure issues also. https://dewey.dunnington.ca/post/2017/line-by-line-row-by-row.../

Comment: Why parquet instead of loading and processing into a database / sql engine like DuckDB or sqlite?